# Python coding question needs clarification

Tags: python

I have a question in myprogramminglab for python.

You work for a bakery that sells two items: muffins and cupcakes. The number of muffins and cupcakes in your shop at any given time is stored in the variables muffins and cupcakes, which have been defined for you.
Write a program that takes strings from standard input indicating what your customers are buying ("muffin" for a muffin, "cupcake" for a cupcake). If they buy a muffin, decrease muffins by one, and if they buy a cupcake, decrease cupcakes by 1. If there is no more of that baked good left, print ("Out of stock").
Once you are done selling, input "0", and have the program print out the number of muffins and cupcakes remaining, in the form "muffins: 9 cupcakes: 3" (if there were 9 muffins and 3 cupcakes left, for example).

### Here is the code that I used

```
#defining initial number of muffins and cupcakes
muffins=10
cupcakes=5
#displaying initial number of muffins and cupcakes
print('Initial Stock: muffins:',muffins,'cupcakes: ',cupcakes)
choice=""
#looping until user enters 0
while choice!="0":
    #getting choice
    choice=input('What do you want? (muffin/cupcake or 0 to quit): ')
    #validating the input
    if choice.lower()=="muffin":
        #checking if there is enough stock left
        if muffins>0:   
            #decreasing the stock, and printing a message
            muffins-=1
            print('You bought a muffin. Number of muffins left:',muffins)
        else:
            #not enough stock, printing a message
            print('Out of stock!')
    elif choice.lower()=="cupcake":
        if cupcakes>0:
            cupcakes-=1
            print('You bought a cupcake. Number of cupcakes left:',cupcakes)
        else:
            print('Out of stock!')
    elif choice=="0":
        #end of loop, displaying the remaining number of muffins and cupcakes
        print('muffins:',muffins,'cupcakes: ',cupcakes)
    else:
        print('Invalid input, try again!')
```

---

[Click here for the picture of the error message showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21l9Z.png)

_stdin
→
_stdout
#1
_stdin.txt: 'muffin

→
_stdout.txt: 'Initial Stock: muffins: 10 cupcakes:  5

The value of _stdout is incorrect.
#2
_stdin.txt: 'muffin

→
_stdout.txt: 'Initial Stock: muffins: 10 cupcakes:  5

The value of _stdout is incorrect.
Hide
#3
_stdin.txt: 'cupcake

→
_stdout.txt: 'Initial Stock: muffins: 10 cupcakes:  5

The value of _stdout is incorrect.

Comment: Are you able to run this program on your machine? I see the output looks like that of an online judge.

Comment: works OK in my env

Comment: These kind of automated systems (The evaluator) is not that smart. See the question never said write the remaining good after one buys it. May printing the left good be the problem?

Comment: "Click here for the picture" - no, I'm not going to do that.  Your question needs to be COMPLETE.

Comment: OP. I hope you are not discouraged. Just accept the answer if that worked for you. And try better when you're asking your next question.

Comment: This did work in my test environment. My apologies as this is my first time posting. The picture shows the screenshot of the error, and I did post the results in the posting. The issue is that the myprogramminglab does not like the syntax or code or whatever it is expecting.

Answer (score 2):

A tool like this isn't going to allow much flexibility in the expected response. To get it "correct" you will need to output exactly what the evaluation logic expects, without variation.

When I read the question I see that the program should only output two things:

- "Out of stock" if user asks for something that is out of stock, or
- A message like "muffins: 9 cupcakes: 3" after the user is finished ordering.

I would first make sure that the program only provides the expected output. Your program outputs an "Initial Stock" message, and multiple "You bought a..." messages. It's very possible that these are causing the failure that you're seeing.

Comment: Kirk: I agree with you and I have found the wordsmithing the code is what needs to be done except in this case. I will keep trying. Thanks for responding. My apologies as I am new to this, and was just seeking help.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately this site rewards users for reporting "low quality questions". This question was closed because it's "not about programming" - I think that's debatable, but I agree that it's mostly about the platform you're using rather than a problem with your program. Hopefully you won't be turned off.